# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 on g95

Tags: python, macos, scipy, fortran

When I try to install the scipy I  have got this error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

error: Command "/opt/local/bin/g95 -shared -shared build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/scipy/interpolate/src/dfitpackmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/fortranobject.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/scipy/interpolate/src/dfitpack-f2pywrappers.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7 -lfitpack -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/scipy/interpolate/dfitpack.so" failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-root/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-IUskjj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-root/scipy
Storing complete log in /Users/MyUser/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

I installed the fortran compiler g95 using mac ports. Install using brew is not an option.

the command is:

```
sudo pip install scipy
```

Comment: If I remember well, OSX uses Mach-O object format, with the capability of storing in the same file, code fore multiple architectures. I suspect your message means you have only 32 bit binaries.

Comment: Scipy is a bit difficult to install. On Linux, I had to download the sources via `pip` and then follow the instructions from [scipy.org](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/index.html). Btw, I think `gfortran` is preferred over `g95`.